# How can I make a yes or no button with multiple inputs?

Tags: python

So, I was looking at a guessing game that I made, and I saw that I had a function that repeats the game, so when you lose or win you can start over again. But when looking at it I wanted to make it so the user could put multiple answers such as "YES", "YE", "Y" where it would still work, and the same thing for no.

This is what I have.

```
def again():
>>>   yes = ["YES", "Y"])

     again = input("Would you like to play again? Y or N: ").upper()
>>>   if again == yes[0] or again == yes[1]: #How could I make this shorter, where it takes the list and just puts the values in? What I have works, but I don't like how it looks and I was wondering if there was a way to make it shorter.
        guess_again()
```

Comment: if again in yes:

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer That worked perfectly, thank you!